# Sobre o digest loop do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Apesar de trabalhar com o AngularJS há algum tempo, nunca consegui compreender como funciona o seu digest loop. Gostaria de entender melhor sobre o mesmo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada: [NG-Book](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) e [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nessa serie de video aulas do Rodrigo Branas, ele explica muito bem como funciona

[Video Aulas](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb)

Nesse video ele foca no digest cycle e dá dicas de como melhorar a performace

[Digest cycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kIorm_gCO4&index=16&list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb)